# Select record value based on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, range

I have the following two tables:

```
ITEM AREA YEAR  MONTH   DAY QTY OL  EXQTY   EXOL    CREATE DATE UPDATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------    
ABC789  XYZ1234 2012    6   22  0   0   0   0   2012/07/04  2012/09/03
ABC789  XYZ1234 2012    6   23  0   0   0   0   2012/07/04  2012/09/03
ABC789  XYZ1234 2012    6   24  0   0   0   0   2012/07/04  2012/09/03
ABC789  XYZ1234 2012    6   25  0   0   0   0   2012/07/04  2012/09/03
ABC789  XYZ1234 2012    6   26  0   0   0   0   2012/07/04  2012/09/03
ABC789  XYZ1234 2012    6   27  0   0   0   0   2012/07/04  2012/09/03
```

and

```
STDATE      EDDATE       FYYEAR  FYMONTH
---------------------------------------
2012/04/23  2012/05/27   2012      11
2012/05/28  2012/06/24   2012      12
2012/06/25  2012/07/22   2013       1
2012/07/23  2012/08/26   2013       2
```

I need to create a new view with all the data from the first table as well as the `FYYEAR` and `FYMONTH` from the second table. The criteria is that if the sale date in the first table (`YEAR MONTH DAY`) is between the `STDATE` and `EDDATE` in the second table, then the correct `FYYEAR` and `FYMONTH` should be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select table1.*, fyyear, fymonth
from table1 
    inner join table2 
    on convert(date,convert(varchar(4),table1.year)+'-'+convert(varchar(4),table1.month)+'-'+convert(varchar(4),table1.day),120)
    between table2.stdate and table2.eddate
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select t1.*,
       FYYEAR ,
       FYMONTH 
from   tbl_1 t1
join   tbl_2 t2
on     cast([YEAR] as char(4))+'-'+
       cast([MONTH] as varchar(2))+'-'+
       cast([DAY] as varchar(2)) 
       between STDATE and EDDATE
```